# Why does this query refuse to finish on my master MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

So, at my work we have a master and a slave going in replication, and we have a tracking table that gets hammered, lots of inserts with an 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' clause. The table is InnoDB, so it locks on the row level. I have this one query that selects data from the stuff currently being written to, but it behaves differently on the master vs the slave, namely that on the master it'll never finish and on the slave it'll finish instantly, and want to know why.

I can understand that the query would have issues dealing with the volatile rows that are being updated, but that's also happening on the slave, albeit at more regular intervals.

```
SELECT SUM(hits) AS hits, DATE(`when`) AS thedate
FROM tracking tr
WHERE tr.geo_country IN('FR') 
AND tr.`when` BETWEEN '2013-08-23 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-23 23:59:59'
GROUP BY thedate
```

No locking is happening on either server, none other than on a single row basis that can't be seen by show processlist.

Comment: You're saying on the master, the query hangs?  Times out?  What's in the processlist for the thread where the query is running?

Comment: how is your table shema ?

Comment: some sample data maybe

Comment: and an example of those `on duplicate key update` queries, please.

Comment: why when why no some meaningful non reserved names

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: On the master it just hangs, on the slave it ends within a minute

@echo_Me: table schema is (**when, geo_country**, hits), where `when` values are 30 min intervals (00:00:00, 00:30:00, 01:00:00, etc)

Comment: INSERT INTO tracking
('2013-08-23 12:30:00', 'GB', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
hits = hits+1

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (the same query) on master and slave and add the results to your question...